# Using handlebar to execute whole page under a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

This is my div section -

```
<div data-role="content" class="school"> 

</div>
```

and this is my main.js

```
$(function  () {
var context = {school: "<div data-role='page'>"
                "<ul data-role='listview' id='unorderedList'>"
                "<li><a href='nl.html' data-icon='grid'>News Letter</a></li>"
                "<li><a href='school.html' data-icon='star' >School News</a></li>"
                "<li><a href='settings.html' data-icon='gear'>Settings</a></li>"
                "</ul>" 
            "</div>"}
var html    = template(context);
});
```

Comment: "i" "dont" "think" "it" "works" "that" "way" -- Also, you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: then whats the correct way

Comment: You can use + to join string together.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function  () {
var context = "<div data-role='page'>\
                <ul data-role='listview' id='unorderedList'>\
                <li><a href='nl.html' data-icon='grid'>News Letter</a></li>\
                <li><a href='school.html' data-icon='star' >School News</a></li>\
                <li><a href='settings.html' data-icon='gear'>Settings</a></li>\
                </ul>\
            </div>"
$('.school').html(context);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9LCdw/7/)